# Time to rounded minutes

Tags: vba, excel

I have this values in Excel cells:

```
 Time        Dev         Total
 00:47:53    00:03:40     50
```

I'm using VBA to calculate my "Total" value:

```
 Minute(Cells(2, 1).Value) + (Minute(Cells(2, 2).Value))
```

This returns 50. I want to to take in consideration the seconds, and return 52, as the seconds would ad up to 93 extra seconds, which make more than a minute and a half. So it must round up to 52

How must I adjust my VBA code?

Answer (score 2):

The VBA `Minute` function will always truncate, and its return values are limited to integers in the range `0...59`.

Try this instead:

```
Function sumMinutes(d1 As Date, d2 As Date) As Long
    sumMinutes = CLng((d1 + d2) * 1440)
End Function
```

Excel stores dates as days and fractions of a day.  Since there are 1440 minutes in a day, multiplying the Excel date by 1440 will give the number of minutes.  Using `CLng` then effectively rounds the value.

**EDIT**: Note that because the VBA rounding algorithm rounds to the nearest even number (so-called bankers rounding), some times that fall ***EXACTLY*** at the 30 second mark, may round down instead of up.  If this is an issue for you, instead of using the VBA `CLng`, you can use the `WorksheetFunction.Round` method.